# Is this happening because I didn't set url right or ajax is wrong or the app itself?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm using django-favorite app from https://bitbucket.org/last_partizan/django-favorites it almost works. It's at the point I have like button and if I click it, it takes me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/favorites/fav/9/14/ but it should be ajax. After being clicked and the error is being shown, if I go back I see 1 person likes this
and like button is changed to unlike. So it kinda works. I;m not sure how to fix this error: TypeError at /favorites/fav/9/14/
**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'
Here's my code. here's views.py for favorite.

```
def ajax_login_required(view_func):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        json = simplejson.dumps({'not_authenticated': True})
        return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json', status=401)
    wrap.__doc__ = view_func.__doc__
    wrap.__dict__ = view_func.__dict__
    return wrap

@ajax_login_required
def ajax_fav(request, ctype_id, obj_id):
    """

    """
    ctype = get_object_or_404(ContentType, pk=ctype_id)
    item = ctype.get_object_for_this_type(pk=obj_id)    
    if Favorite.objects.filter(user=request.user, content_type=ctype, object_id=obj_id):
        fav = Favorite.objects.get(user=request.user, content_type=ctype, object_id=obj_id)
        fav.delete()
        count = Favorite.objects.favorites_for_object(item).count()
        data_dict = {'id': 0, 'message': fav_settings.FAV_ADD, 'counter': build_message(count), }
    else:        
        fav = Favorite.objects.create_favorite(item, request.user)
        count = Favorite.objects.favorites_for_object(item).count()
        data_dict = {'id': fav.id, 'message': fav_settings.FAV_REMOVE, 'counter': build_message(count), }
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data_dict), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

Error is occurring from `return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)` and `return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data_dict), mimetype='application/javascript')`

Here's urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^fav/(?P<ctype_id>\d+)/(?P<obj_id>\d+)/$', 'favorites.views.ajax_fav', name="ajax_fav"),        
)
```

template for favorite

```
<a class="favIt" id="FavIt_{{ item.id }}" href="{% url 'ajax_fav' ctype.id item.id %}">{{ message }}</a>
```

{{ counter }}

and js file

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'a.favIt', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var itemId = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1],
            csrf = $('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
        if (!csrf) console.log("You must add {% csrftoken %} somewhere in the template.");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr("data-action-url"),
            data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf},
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 2000,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                //$("#loader").fadeIn();
            },
            error: function(data, XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                $(this).html("Error connecting to the server.");
            },
            complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                //$("#loader").fadeOut();
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                $('#FavIt_'+itemId).html(data.message);
                $('#FavCounter_'+itemId).html(data.counter);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I don't mean to dump my code here, but really not sure how to fix this. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Add the complete error traceback.

Comment: @AlexMorozov, it can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/lampp365/gv3bvk9d/1/

Comment: Anoop is right, you're passing a wrong keyword argument.

Comment: @AlexMorozov, still not working....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 'content_type' instead of mimetype

Comment: Thank you the error is gone but it still takes me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/favorites/fav/9/18/ with {"message": "like", "counter": "", "id": 0} content...which means ajax isn't working I think

Answer (score 1):

```
mimetype has been deprecated for a long time and has been removed
```

Comment: yeah I'm using pretty outdated app, btw do you know why it  takes me to 127.0.0.1:8000/favorites/fav/9/18 with {"message": "like", "counter": "", "id": 0} content

Comment: oh ok I would be super appreciatted if you can tell me where this code goes into favs =  Favorite.objects.favorites_for_user(user), on documentation https://bitbucket.org/last_partizan/django-favorites it says that code brings all fav

Comment: whats error after replacing mimetype with content-type

Comment: When I click like button it should work as ajax but it takes me to 127.0.0.1:8000/favorites/fav/9/18 with {"message": "like", "counter": "", "id": 0} content